# List that references other class elements

Tags: c#

```
class LINE
{
    public List<string> data = new List<string>();
}

class A
{
    public string num { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I have 2 classes and what I am trying to do is, when change values of **listA** it changes on the **LINES** list as well.

```
List<A> listA = new List<A>();
List<LINE> LINES = new List<LINE>();

A temp = new A();
temp.name = "test";
temp.num = "10";
listA.Add(temp);

LINE l = new LINE();
l.data.Add(temp.num);
l.data.Add(temp.name);
LINES.Add(l);

listA.Last().num = "30"; // it changes LINES value as well
```

Comment: `listA.Last().num = "30";` can't change the value of Lines's Data object as both are different reference. Unable to repro, check the fiddle -- [https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYZlNO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jYZlNO)

Comment: **What have you tried?** There's nothing in C# that would do this automatically. But it's not hard to arrange things so that one list tracks the origin of its data so that when that data changes, the list can be updated. Please explain what you've tried so far, and what _specifically_ you are having trouble with and need help with. Be sure to include a good [mcve] that illustrates these aspects. I will note that the most obvious answer is to make `LINE` have a `List<A>` instead of a `List<string>` and reconstruct the text from the `A` instance any time it's needed.

Answer (score -1):

You examples will work in C++, but C#, is not C++.

Each string in C# is uniq object. List, stores the references to string.
In your case

```
temp.num = "10"; //field num has referenced to string "10"
l.data[0];// Referenced to string "10" too
```

So, when you call

```
listA.Last().num = "30"; //now temp.num has referenced to string "30"
l.data[0];// But this still referenced to string "10" too
```

In C++ you work with std::string as char*, but in C# (and Java too) you work with references. So when you write listA.Last().num = "30" you create new char* and pointer to it. (Not change)